# Bluetooth misbehavior when W10 phone paired with my Uconnect car

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Windows 10 Phone (Lumia 950) which I had paired with my previous car's Uconnect system (2017 Grand Cherokee) and it all worked well enough.
I have traded in the car for a 2021 which has an upgraded Uconnect system; after pairing my phone to the new car I have encountered a weird Bluetooth problem as follows:

I received a text message in-car which the Uconnect system read for me, no problem. But afterwards, the phone would no longer disconnect after I left the car (ignition off, locked, etc.). Even if I try to turn off Bluetooth in the phone, it immediately turned back on and maintained its connection to the car, so the phone's speaker remained disabled in favor of the Bluetooth connection. The only way to reset the connection was to restart the phone. At this point "normal" behavior seemed restored, but I think the problem will recur the next time I use the phone in-car.

Is this a known problem? Is there any known remedy?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer. Uconnect knows how to both display and read texts from the phone, and Cortana can also read texts. Turns out there is a Cortana setting "Read incoming text messages aloud" which was turned on (Cortana/Hamburger/Notebook/Settings/Read incoming text messages aloud). Turning off this setting seems to have resolved the issue.